# Which regions have access to Inventors?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, class, golarion

I want to use [Gadgets](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1621), but they are uncommon. Inventors and regions with access to Inventors have access to uncommon gadgets.

So I check access to [Inventors](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=19), where the only mention of access is about [PFS](https://2e.aonprd.com/PFS.aspx):

> All Pathfinder Society agents have access to the Inventor class.

So which region do I have have to come from to have access to Gadgets as a non-Inventor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Quite a few Regions

From the opening section of the  *Guns & Gears* chapter about Gears Characters there are several locations characters could be from which grant access to the Inventor class, separated by the types of inventions common to those regions. These sections are unfortunately not available on the official Pathfinder SRD Archives of Nethys.

### Clockwork

> Characters from **Absalom**, **New Thassilon**, **Alkenstar**,
> **Dongun Hold**, or especially technological regions of
> **Arcadia** like the **Deadshot Lands** have access to the
> inventor class, as well as uncommon options involving
> clockworks from the first two chapters.

### Magitechnology

> **Uomoto** characters, characters from **Eihlona**,
> automatons with memories of **Jistka**, and **Arcadians**
> all have access to the inventor class (page 15), as well
> as uncommon magitechnological options from the first
> two chapters of this book.

### Stasian Technology

> Characters
> from **Ustalav** have access to the inventor class.

Answer (score 2):

### Possible regions might be Varisia, Absalom, or northern Garund

I think this is only or relevance if you want to play in Pathfinder Society. At your home table, it is up to you what classes you allow.

For regions [Technology in Golarion Today](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1643) has this

> artificers in **Varisia, Absalom**, and **northern Garund** constantly create new devices both wondrous and terrible.

While it does not say inventors outright, creating new devices is effectively invention.