# Which skill feat is necessary to craft Gadgets?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, crafting

[Craft as a Downtime activity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=43) specifies that you need specific skill feats for different types of items:

> You need the Alchemical Crafting skill feat to create alchemical items, the Magical Crafting skill feat to create magic items, and the Snare Crafting feat to create snares.

Gadgets do not fit in either of these categories. Does this mean no skill feat is necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No Skill Feat Necessary

As you've noted, gadgets aren't in any group of items requiring additional feats to Craft so the only requirements are those shared by all items.

> - The item is your level or lower. An item that doesn't list a level is level 0. If the item is 9th level or higher, you must be a master in Crafting, and if it's 16th or higher, you must be legendary.
> - You have the formula for the item; see Getting Formulas for more information.
> - You have an appropriate set of tools and, in many cases, a workshop. For example, you need access to a smithy to forge a metal shield, or an alchemist's lab to produce alchemical items.

As all [gadgets](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1621) are uncommon or rare, getting the formula may prove difficult depending on the setting. Characters from some regions automatically gain access to such items:

> Due to the use of technology, all gadgets are uncommon or rare, though inventors and [regions with access to inventors](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204305/72765) have access to uncommon gadgets.